# null values in Scenario Outline under Examples is considered as string in Karate

Tags: karate

*reqres.feature*

```
Feature: Reqres api test cases
Scenario Outline: register user post -data driven test of negative scenarios
    Given url 'https://reqres.in/api'
    And path 'register'
    And def payload =
      """
      {
      "email": "<email>",
      "password": "<password>"
      }
      """
    And request payload
    When method post
    Then status 400
    * print response
    * match response == <errorResponse>

    Examples: 
      | email | password | errorResponse                          |
      | null  | null     | {"error": "Missing email or username"} |
```

Because of this I am getting response {
"error": "Note: Only defined users succeed registration"
} instead of this response {"error": "Missing email or username"}. How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please spend some time reading the docs here: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#scenario-outline-enhancements

I have re-written your test below. Note the use of the `!` suffix in the `Examples:` column names.

```
Feature: reqres api test cases

  Scenario Outline: data driven test of negative scenarios
    Given url 'https://reqres.in/api'
    And path 'register'
    And request { email: '#(email)', password: '#(password)' }
    When method post
    Then status 400
    And match response == errorResponse

    Examples:
      | email! | password! | errorResponse!                         |
      | null   | null      | { error: 'Missing email or username' } |
```